# Building mobile app in Web API and WCF

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am a new bee to Web API. I have a basic question. 
What is the difference between building a mobile app in Web API and WCF ?

Comment: Have you done any research?If yes, mention what you understood,etc

Comment: Yes Satej S, I did, but most of them I see is Web API is light weight than WCF. Web API is designed to work on PC's and mobiles etc. I have not even concluded of where Web API is a great replace for WCF web services.